# Which tier is responsible for ensuring data integrity

Tags: database, architecture, software-quality

If I have a table in sql. This table has a field called employee.
When a front-end tier calls for this information, where is the responsibility to ensure that employee is not null. i.e. Does a null employee, which by database design, can not happen, be included in any unit tests up front that are reading table information?

i.e. How are contracts handled among different tiers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not validate data while fetching (generally). It should happen while you are performing insert/update. During then, UI and business layer must check for validity of data.

At the database layer as well it must be implemented through constraints.